# Error Cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, types, arguments

Code:

```
public void checkHitDiscount(WineCase wineCase1)
{
    if(hits%10==0)
    {   
        wineCase1.setPrice()=0.9*wineCase1.getPrice;
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You qualify for 10% discount.");
    } else 
        System.out.println("You do not qualify for discount.");
}
```

The error I get here is:

> Method setPrice cannot be applied to given types. required double,
>   found no argument.

I am trying to get a `price` field in the `WineCase` class modified. It is a double.

Comment: Try `wineCase1.setPrice(0.9*wineCase1.getPrice());` You need to pass a double argument to the method and you're actually passing nothing.

Comment: can you post code for your `setPrice()` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPrice()` is a method.  You seem to also have a method called `getPrice()`, and these both probably corresponded to an instance variable called `price` within your object.

If `price` is `private`, then you call `getPrice()` as such:

```
wineCase1.getPrice();
```

This returns a `double` (assuming `price` is of type double).

And again, if `price` is `private`, then you'll need to set it as such:

```
wineCase1.setPrice(somePrice);
```

So in you're above example, if you want to set `price` to 90% of what it's currently at, the proper syntax would look like this:

```
wineCase1.setPrice(0.9*wineCase1.getPrice());
```

---

Alternatively, you could potentially write a `public` method for this class that looks like this:

```
public void discountBy(double disc) {
    price *= 1.0 - disc;
}
// or like this:
public void discountTo(double disc) {
    price *= disc;
}
// or both...
```

To use this method and apply a 10% discount to `wineCase1`, you'd do this:

```
wineCase1.discountBy(0.1);
// or like this:
wineCase1.discountTo(0.9);
```

Then you'll still use:

```
wineCase1.getPrice();
```

To retrieve the private variable, `price`, from the object.

---

And finally, this might potentially be the best solution, add these methods:

```
public double getPriceDiscountedBy(double disc) {
    return price*(1.0-disc);
}

public double getPriceDiscountedTo(double disc) {
    return price*disc;
}
```

These methods will allow you to retrieve the value of the discounted price without changing the original price of the item.  These would be called in the same place you'd get a `getPrice`, but take a discount argument to modify only the returned price.  For example:

```
double discountedPriceOutsideOfObject = wineCase1.getPriceDiscountedTo(0.9);
//or like this:
double discountedPriceOutsideOfObject = wineCase1.getPriceDiscountedBy(0.1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If price field is double type then you simply do like below.

```
public void checkHitDiscount(WineCase wineCase1)
{
    if(hits%10==0)
    {   
        wineCase1.setPrice(0.9*wineCase1.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You qualify for 10% discount.");
    } else 
        System.out.println("You do not qualify for discount.");
}
```

And in WineCase.java the setPrice must be like below.

```
pubilc void setPrice(double price) {
  this.price = price;
}
```

You cannot assign any value to methods, but method can return values.